# What does publicPath: "/static/" do in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs

I have a React, express, mongo, webpack app and in `webpack.config.js`, in the `output` object, there's something like:

```js
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist/bundle/",
    publicPath: "/static/",
  }
```

Now, I understand `filename` is the final bundled code, `path` is where the bundle is going to be but what about `publicPath: "/static/"`?

[publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) documentation says-

> It allows you to specify the base path for all the assets within your application.
>
> In development for example, we might have an **assets/** folder that lives on the same level of our index page. This is fine, but what if we wanted to host all these static assets on a CDN in production?

I don't quite understand it. I don't have an **assets/** folder but my assets are in **public/** directory. It has `media` and `stylesheets` folders inside it.

And I don't understand what's going on here too, in my `views/index.ejs` file. I don't have an `index.html` file in my app but rather an `index.ejs` file. Does it seem right? Well, the app seems to be working but I can't seems to understand how.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/bundle.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/afb88cf987.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me out. I've been stuck on this for ages.

Answer (score 0):

`publicPath` refers to where your assets bundle live from the state of where your `index.html` is, so webpack can set the path for you. For example.

```
dist/
     index.html
     bundle/
          bundle.js
          bundle.css
```

In this case, it would be: `publicPath: "./bundle"`

Comment: What's the meaning of `publicPath: "/static/"` ? In production, `webpack` will generate a `/static/` folder that will have `bundle.js` and `bundle.css`? Also, what about the `.jpg, .png` images that I have? Where will they live?

Comment: If you have the Webpack `file-loader` plugin and you do import your image assets like this `import img from './file.png';` then they should live also where `output: path` is placed

Answer (score 0):

The `pubicPath` is where your `index` are going to look for resources so it has to be the same that your server is exposing resources (css, images, fonts, etc) so for example:

if your `server` is runing your app on 8080 like `http://localhost:8080/` and you have this line in your index:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/bundle.css' />
```

Your server will have to serve the `bundle.css` and other resources when it comes `/static` requests